# Why my List<string> isn't totaly written in my .CSV?

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

I'm trying to write a .csv file in C# from a `list<string>` with roughly 350 lines (for 13 columns).
I write in the file with a loop but only a part of my list is written in the file (206 lines and a half).
This is my code :

```
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv", true);
        foreach (string s in MyListString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s); // Display all the data
            file.WriteLine(s);    // Write only a part of it
        }
```

Why my file isn't properly filled ? Is there any limit to be considered ?

Comment: No problem. Apologies, as I really should have committed to answering properly as opposed to commenting in passing. I've provided an answer but was just a little slower than Oliver in clicking :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you might need to `Flush` or `Close` the writer. Also, most of the time you'd likely want to wrap the writer in a `using` statement.

Fortunately on dispose it automatically closes the writer, flushing the final batch of items to write, so it also solves your issue as well as disposing with any unmanaged items you are now finished with.

Try the following:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv", true))
{
    foreach (string s in MyListString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s); // Display all the data
        file.WriteLine(s);    // Write only a part of it
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes... I totaly forgot to close the StreamWriter. I'll probably use the syntax as you recommended. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close your stream:

```
using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv", true))
{
    foreach (string s in MyListString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s); // Display all the data
        file.WriteLine(s);    // Write only a part of it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv", true)){
    foreach (string s in MyListString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s); // Display all the data
        file.WriteLine(s);    // Write only a part of it

    }
}
```